# Get Object by ManyToMany-Relationship

Tags: playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to filter documents by a list of tags, both stored in a database with a ManyToMany-Relationship.

Model looked like:

```
public Document extends Model {
     ....
     @ManyToMany
     public List<Tag> tagList;

     public static findDocumentsByTags(List<Tag> tags)
     {
     // Here i need help.....
     }
}
```

how do i get the list of documents from the db? the needed data is correctly save by saveManyToManyAssociations and the db looks fine. Just needed the function for ebean

thanks for any support

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need the entity annotation and if necessary the table name:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="table_name_of_documents")
public Document extends Model {
```